# How to get a random number that is not in a blacklist of integers?

Tags: python

I'd like to be able to get random integers except for numbers in my `blacklist` array, I'm having some trouble understanding how I can iterate the code again till it finds the good number.

**Python**

```
def viewName(...):
    random_int = random.randint(0, 11)
    blacklist = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 10]

    for bl in blacklist:
        if random_int == bl:
            #try again till there's a number that isn't in the blacklist
        else:
            correctNumber = random_int
...
```

This seems pretty basic but I don't understand how I can iterate over and over till there's a good number, what is the fastest and more efficient way to achieve this, any suggestion?

Comment: you can use recursion

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44349083/2759780) might help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than re-sampling, just sample from pre-prepared data with the blacklisted items already removed:

```
import random

choices = list(set(range(12)).difference(blacklist))
n = random.choice(choices)
```

Answer (score 2):

In python there is no do...while. I would do the following:

```
def viewName(...):
    blacklist = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 10]
    random_int = 1
    while random_int in blacklist:
        random_int = random.randint(0, 11)
```