# Random selection from list avoiding a given element (negative sampling)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a list of item pairs, where each item is indexed by a numeric id.

E.g.

| item_1 | item_2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 5 |
| .. | .. |

The number pairs are not necessarily aranged from 0 and might not include all values in between (e.g. item 7 could exist, even though item 6 is not in the dataset).

I sample random pairs from this list and want to create multiple negative samples (i.e. samples that do not exist) for each positive sample.

Currently, my code looks like this, but is taking way too long:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

num_neg_samples = 4

# sample data
rng = np.random.default_rng()

all_pairs = pd.DataFrame({
    'TARGET_ID': rng.choice(1_000_000, size=500_000, replace=True),
    'CONTEXT_ID': rng.choice(1_000_000, size=500_000, replace=True)
})
pair_sample = all_pairs.sample(10240)
print(pair_sample.head())

import time
start = time.time()
targets = np.repeat(pair_sample['TARGET_ID'].values,(num_neg_samples+1),axis=0)
contexts = pair_sample['CONTEXT_ID']
negids = []
print(f'{len(pair_sample["TARGET_ID"])} target_ids to create neg samples for')
for index, target_id in enumerate(pair_sample['TARGET_ID']):
    neg_samples = rng.choice(
        all_pairs.loc[all_pairs['TARGET_ID'] != target_id, 'TARGET_ID'].values, 
        size=num_neg_samples
    )
    negids.append(neg_samples)

print(time.time() - start, 'seconds')

batch = (negatives, contexts, targets)
```

Result:

```
        TARGET_ID  CONTEXT_ID
252373       5238      953345
290732     589947      869541
124135     365468      373147
129140     566125      542728
450409     688717      936377

10240 target_ids to create neg samples for
26.611750602722168 seconds
```

I am sampling batches of 10240 pairs per training round. Thus, I would like to end up with 40960 negative pairs, 4 for each "target item" in my dataset.

Does anyone have a good idea how to speed up this code? Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: As the question came up: The pairs are items that appear in a search result together. I want to train a model similar to word2vec or an autoencoder, that generates a embedding that is similar for items that appear together in a search result. To improve the embeddings, I would like to train with negative samples as well, i.e. pairs of items that do not appear in the search results together.

EDIT2: Please note, that the pairs I have available might include duplicates, i.e. multiple times the same exact pair. Each item id will appear multiple times in both `item_1` and `item_2` columns.

Comment: Looks like `targets` and `contexts` variables are not even used

Comment: BTW you're passing the `replace=False` parameter when creating `all_pairs`, which is weird because you 're showing an example at the very beginning with duplicate values in both `item_1` and `item_2`  columns. So why are you using `replace=False`?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, the targets, contexts and negatives are later used down the road. I edited my question to reflect that.

Comment: @Vitalizzare, thanks for the comment. The `all_pairs` are generated for the sake of the example here, but you are right, it should be `replace=True` :-)

Comment: @Vitalizzare I updated my question to explain in more detail what the use case is and what negative samples refer to.

Answer (score 2):

Slicing a DataFrame is expensive. Using pure python and sets was 5 times faster for me:

```
num_neg_samples = 4

targets = set(pair_sample['TARGET_ID'])

negids = [rng.choice(list(targets-{t}), size=num_neg_samples, replace=False)
          for t in pair_sample['TARGET_ID']]
```

Output:

```
[array([563401, 169859, 180204, 953531]),
 array([310634,  27685, 992711, 801847]),
 array([519938, 717685, 150933, 466746]),
 array([496852, 370208, 930286, 293928]),
 ...
]
```

Using python's [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) is 10 times faster:

```
num_neg_samples = 4

targets = set(pair_sample['TARGET_ID'])

negids = [random.sample(list(targets-{t}), k=num_neg_samples)
          for t in pair_sample['TARGET_ID']]
```

Comment: I think it may be not a good decision, and here is why. When you convert a sequence to a set, you are eliminating repeated values. Probably in this approach it would be correct to add weights for each unique value with a random selection. Or you need to clarify what exactly the author means by negative samples.

Comment: @Vitalizzare it's true that duplicates are ignored, that said given OP's example sampling 500k among 1M*1M combinations leaves almost no chance for duplicates.

Comment: `all_pairs` will contain duplicates in the real data. Sorry for the bad example and its caused confusion. Thus, a solution that eliminates duplicates would not be suitable in my case. 
I will update my question accordingly.

Comment: @Lukas please update with a meaningful minimal reproducible example, no `...` and examples of the matching expected output.

Answer (score 1):

You can speed up the processing by using [`concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor) to collect filtered negative samples in parallel threads. I get **4**-**5**x increase in speed on my machine (the initial approach: ~93 sec, threads: ~20 sec):

```
import time
from concurrent import futures
from functools import partial

def select_neg_sample(target_id, all_pairs, size=4):
    return rng.choice(
        all_pairs.loc[all_pairs['TARGET_ID'] != target_id, 'TARGET_ID'].values,
        size=size
    )

start = time.time()
targets = np.repeat(pair_sample['TARGET_ID'].values, (num_neg_samples + 1), axis=0)
contexts = pair_sample['CONTEXT_ID']
print(f'{len(pair_sample["TARGET_ID"])} target_ids to create neg samples for')

with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    it = executor.map(partial(select_neg_sample, all_pairs=all_pairs),
                      pair_sample['TARGET_ID'])
    neg_ids = list(it)

print(time.time() - start, 'seconds')
print(f'neg_ids size: {len(neg_ids)}, last entry: {neg_ids[-1]}')
```

---

```
        TARGET_ID  CONTEXT_ID
294231     704025      731665
22308      430988      862487
484542      70459      196505
119601     762881      339710
309284     459537      433841
10240 target_ids to create neg samples for
19.128324270248413 seconds
neg_ids size: 10240, last entry: [ 33955 538037 312413 692326]
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. In my actual code I am already using multiprocessing and in this post I am working on optimizing each single processor script. For the sake of simplicity I kept this out of my question, so that its easier to follow. Nevertheless, thumbs up.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @mozway's answer and this one, I found in a related post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44349133/5240684, i came up with the following, that is sufficient for my case:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time

num_neg_samples = 4

# sample data
rng = np.random.default_rng()

all_pairs = pd.DataFrame({
    'TARGET_ID': rng.choice(100_000, size=500_000, replace=True),
    'CONTEXT_ID': rng.choice(100_000, size=500_000, replace=True)
})
pair_sample = all_pairs.sample(10240)
print(pair_sample.head())

start = time.time()
unique_targets = all_pairs['TARGET_ID'].unique()
# index to be able to use range
unique_targets_indexed = dict(zip(unique_targets, range(len(unique_targets))))
        
targets = pair_sample['TARGET_ID'].values
contexts = pair_sample['CONTEXT_ID'].values

negative_targets = np.repeat(pair_sample['TARGET_ID'].values,(num_neg_samples),axis=0)
negative_contexts = [unique_targets[random_neg(0,len(unique_targets), unique_targets_indexed[t])] for t in negative_targets]
print(f'\nTook {time.time() - start} seconds')
```

Result:

```
        TARGET_ID  CONTEXT_ID
284483      70099       74132
164208       3090       13895
186524      89871       81281
270224      46461       56410
470391       7434       81272

Took 0.19039297103881836 seconds
```

Even when sampling from 1 mio different target ids, the processing time on my machine increases to only about 0.31 seconds.

The basic idea is to index the target ids to be a range from 0 to len(unique_targets), so that we can sample a random int from a range instead of from a set, as this is way faster.

This way I end up with
`batch = (contexts, targets, negative_contexts, negative_targets)` as my batch.

Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: doesn't it disagree with your initial prerequisites: "*all_pairs will contain duplicates in the real data*" and "*the pairs I have available might include duplicates*" ?

Comment: You are right, it does not sample according to the frequency of each unique item. One way around that could be instead of setting `unique_targets = all_pairs['TARGET_ID'].unique()` to drop the `unique()` so that we sample based on the occurrences in `all_pairs`